# Dynamic add property in object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am working on edit post page and want to submit data if the post field are modify.

```
var req = {
  'apikey': apidata.apikey,
  'partyId': boardID,
}
```

Now I just want to add property which is edited in form.

```
'name':'userName',
'postDetail':'<p>This is detail</p>'
```

What is the best approch to handel this. I looked to the other post but I found

```
var req = {name: 'firstName'};
// data from form
var data = {'age':45, 'city':'london'};
function extend(objectToExtend, data) {
for (var i in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        objectToExtend[i] = data[i];
    }
  }
}
extend(req, data);
```

I think there is more space of improvement in this approch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the new properties using the square bracket notation.

```
var req = {
  'apikey': apidata.apikey,
  'partyId': boardID
};

req['name'] = 'userName';
req['postDetail'] = '<p>This is detail</p>';
```